# Linker error with POSIX-Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I use Dev-C++ 5.5.3.
The linker reports me this error...why?

[image]

Comment: what is the link/compile command line? Probably you're missing including the -lpthreads

Comment: Prefer to post everything(relevant part) on this website rather than providing a link to a different site.

Comment: i dont know how to insert this command...

Comment: You could try inserting a **minimal working example** and the **compiler output**

Comment: Please put all relevant information into your question instead of providing images or links!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why?**

The pthread library is not compatible with Windows. Don't worry, [there is a library for that. Called pthreads-win32](https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/), you could also try `std::thread` but your code seems mostly `c` so better stick to `pthread`

Just downloaded Dev-C++ and checked, mingw does include the header files for `pthread` but don't let this confuse you. Pthread is not compatible with Windows, so the implementation will not link.

#### How to link pthread win32?

Check the Tools -> Compiler Options -> Directories and add the proper directories for your library pthread win32.

And then add the command in Tools -> Compiler Options -> General for your library like this -llibpthread-win32 or the name you installed for the lib on your system.

#### What if I want to go C++ and `std::thread` all over the program

Just check that the version of your mingw for C++11 compatibility by adding the command -std=c++11 to your compiler. I suggest the newest version of g++ 4.8 since it includes the tool thread sanitizer.

Comment: This can't be the problem. If he doesn't have a pthreads implementation, where is `_imp_pthread_create` coming from and why isn't he getting an error at the `#include`?

Comment: Mingw does come with the header files, just checked